# Descargar Archivos de una pagina con login

Tags: c#, vs

les comento que debo realizar un programa en c# en donde debo descargar archivos desde una pagina X, el problema que tengo es que en esta pagina me pide usuario y clave para acceder a descargar y hasta el momento no se me ocurre como ingresar las credenciales a traves de codigo c# y asi tener acceso para poder descargar los archivos...

si alguien me pudiera dar un feedback se lo agradezco!

Comment: Hola, recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 1):

Verifica si el acceso a los archivos es público por lo que podrías descargarlos directamente.
Si la página posee una API publica a la que puedas acceder, debes autenticarte de acuerdo a las opciones que ofrezca la API y obtener un token de acceso, después ese token lo envías en la petición de descarga del archivo.
No te puedo dar más información ya que desconozco a que página tratas de conectarte.